# How to remove last array from below code when name is empty

Tags: php, arrays

Here I want to remove last array from below (this is always last array that is set dynamically):

```
array(1) {
  ["file-1573204001988"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(7) "abc.png"
      ["type"]=>
      string(9) "image/png"
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpdl81UY"
      ["error"]=>
      int(0)
      ["size"]=>
      int(72761)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "profiles.png"
      ["type"]=>
      string(9) "image/png"
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phptIFS1J"
      ["error"]=>
      int(0)
      ["size"]=>
      int(16178)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["error"]=>
      int(4)
      ["size"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to remove whole below array from above (when it have empty name):

```
[2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["error"]=>
      int(4)
      ["size"]=>
      int(0)
    }
```

How this can possible I tried with array_pop, unset and other predefined php functions but not getting the correct result.
Please help me out to reach the correct value
Thanks in advance

Comment: `unset($arr['file-1573204001988'][2]);`

Comment: Its not always [2] its dynamic

Comment: Then you **REALLY** ought to have said that in your question

Comment: So what rules are applied to decide which array shoudl be removed?

Comment: I want to remove last array that should be [2], [3] or any. I got last array as empty thats the issue

Comment: Looks a bit like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can't you solve it by checking the `"error"` value ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)) when processing these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look like items of `$_FILES` array. Instead of checking the name I would recommend checking the value of `error` and filter out anything that's not `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` or `0`

```
$valid_files = array_filter($arr["file-1573204001988"],
     fn($item) => $item['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK);
```

[File upload errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are persistently trying to remove the last element within the array, you can use [`array_pop`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php).

`array_pop()` pops and returns the value of the last element of array, shortening the array by one element.

```php
$myArray = array(
    0 => "hello",
    1 => "world",
    2 => "remove me",
);

array_pop($myArray); // Removes [2] from the array above.
```

In your case, you would simply do:

```php
array_pop($array["file-1573204001988"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple foreach loop with a simple test in it will do this for you

```
foreach ($arr['file-1573204001988'] as $key=>$a){
    if ( $a['name'] = '' ){
        unset($arr['file-1573204001988'][$key]);
    }
}
```